# Did Nietzsche violate Christian morality in his life? Was he urging anyone to do so?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, nietzsche, truth

Did Nietzsche violate Christian morality in his life, in his behaviour? Was he urging anyone to do so? He seems to have had a long standing grudge against it.

Comment: how is this a downvote?

Comment: You do know that in Christianity blasphemy is a sin? And [The Antichrist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Antichrist_(book)), in particular, is an unadulterated stream of it.

Comment: Answer:  No. And perhaps No to your second question. Read some biographies of him and see what you think.

Comment: He apparently frequently went to brothels, which most Christians would consider immoral.

Comment: @confused. Hi. I have closed the question because I don't think N's personal morality is a matter for philosophical concern. I have been asked to adjudicate on your robust language, 'you guys are nuts', which has been taken to be 'unfriendly or unkind'. It isn't the right language for the site, so I have had to delete it even though I take it to be a spontaneous expression of exasperation. It's naturally open to you to make a differently worded comment. Best - Geoffrey

Comment: ok sure, apologies for being riled... @GeoffreyThomas i do think the decision is wrong, that his behaviour could help us understand his writing, as well as beliefs

Comment: Fine, thanks. But your angle that 'his behaviour could help us understand his writing, as well as beliefs'  does not appear to be that of the question. The question is worded in such a way that it appears to be just a biographical inquiry. If the OP didn't intend this, the question needs to be rephrased. Until our next encounter ! Best - Geoffrey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider the Ten Commandments from the Tora also part of Christian morality then Nietzsche violated already the first commandment by his **atheistic** position: Nietzsche did not accept Jahwe being his god.

Comment: wow, i was impressed by how many of those are internal prescriptions!

Comment: @confused. I've upvoted your question and this answer but could you explain your comment : 'wow, i was impressed by how many of those are internal prescriptions! ' It leaves me confused, if you'll excuse the pun.  I make no criticism - I just don't follow. Best - Geoffrey

Comment: i just mean that many of the ten commandments seem to be about an attitude / belief, rather than behaviour (stealing, murder, etc.) @GeoffreyThomas